# Import RS4 object (from RData file) into numPy array

Tags: python, r, numpy, rpy2

I'm able to read in data from an .RData file (vector list of arrays) and I would like to convert these data to a numPy array for easier plotting/viewing.

So far:

[image]

How can I extract the values from the 277,349 raster into a 277,349 numPy array?

Comment: These are .RData files that were saved on disk from a different system. Just trying to find a solution to convert them to numPy for better 2-D plotting solutions (i.e., matplotlib).

Comment: Loud and clear re: the image the first time. I can use R for this purpose, but I am simply asking if there is a way to convert to a 2-D NumPy array. Once again, please read the question. There is no need to suggest "why not just do bla bla bla."